# Never reach smooth, constant 60 fps in 3D applications regardless of graphics settings

Tags: windows, video, graphics-card, performance, framerate

I have a Radeon R9 290 (though this also happened on my previous card, a 6850) and it seems that only a select few games run at a constant, smooth 60fps. This has no relation to graphics settings as it still does this on minimum settings. I can watch a 60fps YouTube video of the same game and notice the smoothness, in comparison to a lot of small stutters on my computer.

Specs:

- AMD Phenom II X4 955 (3.2GHz quadcore)
- 8GB DDR3 1333MHz RAM
- Radeon R9 290
- Windows 10 Pro x64 (this also happened on windows 7.)

It's not that the game completely stutters and pauses, more like it fluctuates around 55-60, thus removing the sense of smoothness you would see from a constant framerate. This happens with vsync on and off.

I have two monitors, which I suspect might be the culprit.

Any ideas for how to fix this? I know I can run these games just fine, especially considering most of what I'm trying to play is 4+ years old.

Comment: Do you have at least 15.7.1 AMD drivers?

Comment: What resolution are you playing? 1024x768,1280x,1024,1920x1080 or what? The 290 simply may not be capable of it.

Comment: Youtube video are pre-rendered so they barely use any GPU and games depend highly on the GPU.

Comment: Running in 1920x1080 on my primary monitor. Driver version 15.20.1062.1004

Comment: I know it's not a matter of GPU power because this still happens on much older games and on minimum settings. This is a high-end card.

Comment: Try the 15.8 Beta driver.  The 290 a high-end card? **No**, the R9 Fury X is a high end card.  Try 1600x1080 or the next lower resolution.

Comment: Now depending on the game it could be CPU bound.  Many older games can only use 1 core and the rest go to waste.  However, since you won't tell us what games your playing we can't check.

Comment: Last one I tried was Diablo 3, the frame rate is especially obvious when moving around. Low and high graphics settings, vsync on or off, real full screen, and bordeerless/windowed. I've also played World of Warcraft, Warframe, Minecraft (although I can just blame minecraft's crappy code for that one), Skyrim, Supreme Commander (though that one's definitely a mixture of poor optimization and CPU usage), Borderlands 2, and Battlefield 4.

Comment: Skyrim is CPU bound for sure, it can't use more than 1 core so it has to be faster.  Upgrading to 1866Mhz memory might help.  You could upgrade your CPU.

Comment: Warframe does almost everything on CPU. WoW is VERY CPU intensive